# Can I summarize multiple records with duplicate column data on one row on my report?

Tags: reporting

We are using Salesforce in our non-profit social services agency to track the hours that our staff spend with clients.  Each interaction they have with the clients staff enter a record in our "Case Notes" custom object which includes the time spent interacting with clients (in .25 hour increments).

For billing purposes, we need to be able to report on the number of hours spent each month with each client, along with some of the clients personal information & the code of the program they are enrolled in.  Other than the hours on each case note record, the data is identical for each interaction.

I am having a hard time summarizing it in a format that works for the billing report, which summarizes all of the hours in the individual case note records for the previous month in one row.  Here is an example of what my report is currently exporting, and what I want it to export:

[image]

Can someone help me out here?  Thank you!!

Comment: Sounds like you want a roll-up summary for the hours fields. What's the relationship for clients to Case Notes? Is it a Master-Detail or just a lookup?

Comment: It is just a look-up.

Comment: Why don't you create a summary report (summaryzing the client's name) in Salesforce? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I can create a summary report in Salesforce that will give me a sum of the hours, but when I export the note using "Export Details" the hours are still displaying in separate records.  By using "Printable View" I will get the summary of the hours, but the rest of the columns do not show up in the summary.

Basically I am needing Salesforce to export all of the records consolidated in one row, like the above screenshot shows.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do it? I am looking for the same solution.

Comment: This is not a salesforce answer, but use a pivot table.  That, or you can run a summary report then click "Printable View"